# Clear an Object already inserted to a hashmap

Tags: java, oop, hashmap

calls is an arrayList, customerCalls is a hashMap. I was debugging using eclipse and I fount that calls.clear clear the arrayList object already inserted in the customerCalls Hashmap. I am confused because I thought that once the object was submitted to another data structure, it has an independent entity and no operations can be taken on it unless I access this data structure containing it.

I need to clear the arrayList calls to make it free for a new set of calls that would be dedicated to another contract and later inserted as value for the hashmap key (contract Number). Not clearing it accumlates all calls as it appends current iteration addition to the past iteration one.

```
>     if (callContractID.equals(currentContractID)==false){
>                               customerCalls.put(currentContractID, calls);
>                               currentContractID =  callContractID;
>                               calls.clear();
>                               calls.add(call);
>                               count++;
>     }
     else {

        calls.add(call);
         }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Passing a reference to object A to another object in no way alters A (unless the other object explicitly invokes a method on A to change its state, of course). It doesn't spawn an independent copy of A, or make A immutable, or anything like that.

It sounds like what you want to do is to just create a new `ArrayList` once you're done with the first one and have submitted it to the map.

```
if (!callContractId.equals(currentContractID) {
    calls = new ArrayList<Call>(); // or whatever the type is
    // rest of your code...
}
```

This will replace the value of `calls` with a reference to a new, empty `ArrayList` that you can add new elements to. The old `ArrayList` will still be available to the `HashMap`, because the map has its own copy of the reference to that first list.

Comment: So if I construct a new array list after submitting the old one to the hashmap any actions I take on calls wont reflect on this already submitted to the hashmap

Comment: Correct. Those operations will take place on the object that `calls` currently references, which is now the new list you constructed.

Answer (score 2):

> I am confused because I thought that once the object was submitted to another data structure, it has an independent entity and no operations can be taken on it unless I access this data structure containing it.

No. The map contains a *reference* to an object... just as if you simply assigned another variable to it. You can have lots of references to the same object, and any changes made via one reference will be seen via any of the others. As a very simple example:

```
StringBuilder b1 = new StringBuilder();
StringBuilder b2 = b1;
b2.append("foo");
System.out.println(b1); // Prints foo
```

The exact same thing happens with collections:

```
StringBuilder b1 = new StringBuilder();
List<StringBuilder> list = new List<StringBuilder>();
list.add(b1);

StringBuilder b2 = list.get(0);
// Now b1 and b2 are both reference to the same object...
b2.append("foo");
System.out.println(b1); // Prints foo
```

Comment: Thank you Jon. Very beneficial and simple illustration as usual :)

Answer (score 1):

Not at all. The object has not been "submitted", it has been passed to another method (it happens that such method has made its own copy of the reference to the object.

All references to the object point to the same object and may call the same methods. The object (usually) has no means to know where it is being called from.